# Salt virtualenv.managed using setup.py

Tags: salt-stack

I have my python package requirements in `setup.py` and I simply do `pip install .` from a directory where `setup.py` exists. I don't have a `requirements` file and I don't want to have one. How do I tell salt to use `setup.py` instead of `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing pip package to virtualenv and running setup.py should be different requirement.

I assume setup.py triggering is only mean for self-serving modules, external package should be put under saltstack virtualenv setup, so you can see if the required external package failed to install.  But it also depends on your own taste.

To run setup.py inside your virtualenv, you must create a script that call the virutalenv, then run setup.py , e.g. vi  run-setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.virtualenv/xyz/bin/activate
cd $HOME/xyz_app
python setup.py
```

then use the cmd.run in state file to run it

```
run setup.py for my xyz app :
  cmd_run:
    - name: bash <xyz_app folder name>/run-setup.sh
    - user: <username>
    - group: <groupname>
```

**UPDATE :**

Since you want to load particular python package to your virtualenv, you can do it straight away during setup. Then only use cmd.run to load batch that launch setup.py (to make your custom app works)into the virtualenv.

```
create-my-apps-virtualenv:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - name: /home/myapphome/.virtualenv/myapp
    - user: myappusername
    - no_chown: False
    # install this pacakge to my virtualenv, package must be case sensitive according. 
    - pip_pkgs: json, MySQL-python,SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: There's no way to do it using `pip.installed` or `virtualenv.managed`? Seems like an important feature. If python modules from `setup.py` are not installed there doesn't seem to be a point for installing packages from `requirements.txt`

Comment: Well, I agree with the salt.modules developer to make them work on niche function.  Execute setup.py as part of those module, IMHO, is bad idea and irrelevant to those modules functionality.

Comment: Ended up doing `cmd.run` with `pip install`. Thank you

Comment: @ebnius : I think probably some misunderstanding, I will add the pip install into the virtualenv.   Updating my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I wanted exactly. My understanding is in python there are two ways to list packages required for the project, setup.py and requirements file(http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements/) My question was, I only see a way in salt to install from a requirements file. I didn't have one. I only had `install_requires` in my `setup.py`. I also don't want to list my package requirements under `virtualenv.managed`. The only way I could get it working was to do a `cmd.run`.

Comment: @ebnius : You wouldn't want to put you setup.py and packages OUTSIDE virtualenv.  Because without virtualenv, you must do "sudo pip". You will run into lots of error if you fail to do so.

Comment: My `cmd.run` had a `require: virtualenv`. The command itself activates the virtualenv and pip installs from `setup.py`